# Using sql column encryption with asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an asp.net application that is used for internal affairs. My boss would feel more comfortable with having some columns of the table encrypted. I know how to do that portion of it however I'm lost on how to display the encrypted columns in plain text on the front end asp web page. I have tried to create a sql view that decrypts the data, which works fine in sql management studio but when the application calls the same view the decrypted column is just blank. Any thoughts?

Comment: if you're providing a view that auto-decrypts the columns, then what's the point of storing the columns crypted in the first place? "here's a bank vault, sealed up with the hardest steel and most impreganable locks. But here's a simple paper window so you don't have to go through all that security to get your stuff out".

Comment: I agree with you @MarcB Do you have a solution on how my application can decrypt the column without doing a view? I've also tried running the sql query (same results the view returns) to no avail.

Comment: don't know about sql server, but I did have a similar directive from a client a while back who didn't understand the problem at all. in mysql, I just ended up doing `aes_decrypt(field, @key)` and `aes_encrypt('string', @key)` everywhere. zero security, more headache, but the client went away happy, secure in the knowledge that their data was encrypted, yet still totally readable.

Answer (score 0):

This was my first thought:

MachineKey.Protect/Unprotect was the first thing that I thought of to directly answer your question of how to encrypt/decrypt.

It may not be the best solution.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Where would I add this into my application?

Comment: Before you insert your data, you'll need to encrypt it with MachineKey.Protect and provide a key.  When you get the data, you'll need to decrypt it (MachineKey.Unprotect) with the same key - otherwise you'll get an exception if you pass an invalid key.

Comment: I'm looking to utilize sql server built in column encryption and not have to encrypt and decrypt on the application side.